# Performance impact of aliasing tables multiple times in a SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, sqlperformance

I am using Spark-SQL. I want to know if there would be any *performance impact* by **aliasing** a table multiple times in the same sql query ?

I have a query like:

```
select 
a.custid, b.descr as prodname, c.descr as storename
from cust a
left join prod b
on a.custid = b.custid
left join prod c
on a.custregion = c.regionid;
```

In the above example, the product table is being used multiple times in the same query with aliases. So will this impact the performance of the query in anyway since the same table is being used multiple times in the same sql ?

Another approach will be to construct individual sqls with the table each time and then combining all the sqls together (as below):

```
--alias prod to get prodname
create temporary view v_prod as
select a.custid, b.descr as prodname
from cust a
left join prod b
on a.custid = b.custid;

--alias prod to get storename
create temporary view v_store as
select a.custid, c.descr as storename
from cust a
left join prod c
on a.custregion = c.regionid;

--combine both sqls
select 
a.custid, b.prodname, c.storename
from cust a
left join v_prod b
on a.custid = b.custid
left join v_store c
on a.custid = c.custid;
```

Can anyone please let me know which one will be better from a performance perspective ?

Thanks

Comment: Most probably the double left join query. Show us the table and index definitions.

Comment: @jarlh - we are using SparkSQL on AWS Glue tables, hence no index concept. Also, i heard sometime back that using aliases in the same sql query runs slower because of locks on the same table by each of the alias instances, which leads to slower execution times. Is that a true statement ?

Answer (score 0):

the use of view in you query  is equivalent as  build two  subquery   eg:

```
select 
      a.custid
    , t1.prodname
    , c.descr as storename
from cust a
left join ( 
  select a.custid, b.descr as prodname
  from cust a
  left join prod b  on a.custid = b.custid
) t1  on a.custid = t1.custid
left join (
  select a.custid, c.descr as storename
  from cust a
  left join prod c on a.custregion = c.regionid
) t2 on t2.cust_id =  c.custid
```

so is clearly more efficent the use of direct left join

```
select 
      a.custid
    , b.descr as prodname
    , c.descr as storename
from cust a
left join prod b on a.custid = b.custid
left join prod c on a.custregion = c.regionid;
```

for better performance be sure you have   a proper index  table prod

```
idx1 on column  custid
idx2 on column   regionid
```

and table  prod a composite

```
idxprod column (custid, custregion)
```